# PHP: How to post hidden field with style='display:none'

Tags: php, html, text, http-post, hidden-field

This doesn't get posted if it's hidden like this, how do i get around it?

```
<input name="Pid" style="display:none"/>
```

and PHP.

```
$Pid = preg_replace ('#[^0-9 ]#i', '', $_POST['Pid']);
```

Comment: you haven't specified a `type` for the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kindly use it as:

```
<input name="Pid" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use hidden field simply setting type as hidden

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="pid"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need your input type to remain, like text or checkbox, use a `<div style='display:none;'></div>` tag to hide your input object.

Sometimes, this is required if your submit code does not include checks like 
`if (isset($_POST['Your_Object_name'])) {...}` 
Sometimes you don't want to show them, but neither do you want your code to issue error messages.

Your code will then be as follows

```
<div style='display:none;'>
    <input name="Pid" type="text" />
</div>
```

Et voila